# Listview ArrayAdapter null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to get an address on onMapLongClick (MAPS activity) method and save the address to a list view. The list view is in a different activity.

I am receiving nullpointerexception . Please see below full trace.

I have reviewed few often posts from Stackoverflow and made the changes to my array adapter, but the null pointer exception still persists

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.wesport, PID: 3082
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.android.wesport.MapsActivity.onMapLongClick(MapsActivity.java:214)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$14.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzn$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                  at ya.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:93)
                  at maps.D.p$2.a(Unknown Source)
                  at maps.V.u.f(Unknown Source)
                  at maps.V.P.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
                  at maps.z.e$b.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
                  at maps.z.c.c(Unknown Source)
                  at maps.z.c$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

LongclickMethod:

```
/* Get address for new places when user long click's on the map) and show the address*/
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    String address="";
    try {
        List<Address> listAddresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);
        if (listAddresses!=null && listAddresses.size()>0){
            if (listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare()!=null){
                if (listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare()!=null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + " ";
                }
                address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                Log.d("address",address);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (address == " "){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm yyyyMMdd");
        address=sdf.format(new Date());
    }
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address));
    MyGames.games.add(address);
    MyGames.locations.add(latLng);
    MyGames.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Games Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

ListviewActivity:

```
static ArrayList<String> games =new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<LatLng> locations=new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_games);
    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    locations.add(new LatLng(0,0));
    games.add ("My Saved Games...");
    if(arrayAdapter.getCount()!=0 && arrayAdapter!=null){
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,games);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Use `arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,games);`

Comment: You never initialized `static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;` and static variables are often bad, anyway

Comment: I just changed it to arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_‌​1,games), and still receiving the error

Comment: Okay, but it probably isn't the exact same error. [Edit] your question with the newest code and error

Comment: Actually, remove `&& arrayAdapter!=null`  because that appears to be  false

Comment: Added  trace. added arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_‌​‌​1,games) and removed &&arrayAdapter!=null condition. It is the same error no changes

Comment: Looks like like you've edited only the error, not the code. Anyways, can you not set a breakpoints and debug where you think the adapter was initialized? That would be quicker than us trying to piece together these two snippets of code you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the static variables . The array adapter was getting initialized incorrectly. I had removed the static variable and used shared preferences to store my Array and retrieve it in another activity